# Will the DataSnapshot here in my code be overwritten because of multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Some Christmas eve multi threading here...:)
Because the FireBase `ChildEventListener` `onChildAdded()` is called for every entry in succession, will the DataSnapshot here in my code be overwritten, like if my thread that I start when it has not finished and a new call to `onChildAdded()` is coming, will the DataSnapshot be changed inside my thread?

```
ChildEventListener userHistoryAddressChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot snapshot, String prevKey) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // get toy history for current user
                UserHistory.ToyHistory toyHistory = snapshot.getValue(UserHistory.ToyHistory.class);
                 ToyManager.getInstance().addToyHistory(
                        mFireBaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(),
                        toyHistory.getToy(),
                        toyHistory.getTime(),
                        toyHistory.getColor(),
                        toyHistory.getHistoryId());  
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to onChildAdded will have its own immutable DataSnapshot instance passed to it.

I highly recommend avoiding starting a new thread like that for each child.  This could easily overwhelm the device or computer it's running on.  If you need to get blocking work off the callback and into another thread, consider using an [Executor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) that can queue work for execution on a bounded pool of threads that's appropriate for the system and your ToyManager, which we can't see how it's implemented.